# What does this RegEX replace expression do?

Tags: regex, postgresql

Folks, I'm a regex newb, and can't suss out what this sucker is doing (btw - %1 is replaced by values coming from a database column which represents a domain like "local" or "stackoverflow.com"):

```
regexp_replace(%1,E'[.]','%'||'2E', 'g')
```

I'm assuming the E above is doing some sort of global conversion - ucase/lcase/unicode/ANSI, etc...but I can't find a reference. It also looks like we're OR-ing the potential replacement characters (% or 2E? Why?) but I'm at a loss.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will replace every dot character by `%2E` wich is the urlencoded of `.`

i.e: `stackoverflow.com` becomes `stackoverflow%2Ecom`

The `||` operator is the concatenation operator not the `OR` operator.